# JSF 2.0 How to link CSS from resources folder

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, jsf-2

I'm designing the template for my new JSF2.0 App and I want to use the resources folder to store my css-file. Now I started to create a template-file, but I don't know how to link the css.

I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>
```

..but didn't work

Can somebody help me, pls.
THX

---

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" target="head" />
```

That doesn't work either :-(

---

It still doesn't work! Maybe that resource-method is disabled?! It doesn't work with pictures either!

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['img:logo.png']}"/>
```

The output in my browser looks like that:

```
<img src="RES_NOT_FOUND">
```

EDIT: Images working now. I stupidly set a wrong path -.- but the stylesheet is still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have h:head/h:body tags.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put public resources in the public webcontent (`/webapp` folder as on your screenshot). CSS files are downloaded/included by webbrowser, not by webserver and hence need to be directly public accessible.

Comment: Thank you for that information. But I have another question: Maven (that I use) wants a folder named 'resources' under src/main. What is that folder for? I thought that's the folder for resources. 
cheers

Answer (score 2):

Create a sub-directory resources at the web application root and try. It will work.

Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girgm.html

Answer (score 0):

It works with plain old html:

```
<link href="./resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But i don't like it I would prefer JSF...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem everything work after switching those two lignes :

from :

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

to :

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
```

Please check the link below:
Reference to CSS under resources folder in jsf.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsf/outputstylesheet-example-with-jsf-2-0/

Comment: This is not the way to do it, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used